# How to get the content of a JSON without showing the names of the key values

Tags: bash, jq

I am new to Bash and I am currently trying to get the content of a JSON without showing the names of the key values.

This is how the JSON looks like (part of it):

```json
[
  {
    "V1": 65,
    "V2": "Female",
    "V3": 0.7,
    "V4": 0.1,
    "V5": 187,
    "V6": 16,
    "V7": 18,
    "V8": 6.8,
    "V9": 3.3,
    "V10": 0.9,
    "Class": 1
  },
  {
    "V1": 62,
    "V2": "Male",
    "V3": 10.9,
    "V4": 5.5,
    "V5": 699,
    "V6": 64,
    "V7": 100,
    "V8": 7.5,
    "V9": 3.2,
    "V10": 0.74,
    "Class": 1
  },
  {
    "V1": 62,
    "V2": "Male",
    "V3": 7.3,
    "V4": 4.1,
    "V5": 490,
    "V6": 60,
    "V7": 68,
    "V8": 7,
    "V9": 3.3,
    "V10": 0.89,
    "Class": 1
  }
]
```

This is my script

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Albumin =3";
echo "Age Sex Albumin  Proteins";
echo "******";
echo " "
echo "Women";
echo "--------------";
cat csvjson.json | jq -c '.[] | {V1, V2, V8, V9} | select(.V9 ==3) | select(.V2 =="Female")';
echo " "
echo "Men";
echo "-------------";
cat csvjson.json | jq -c '.[] | {V1, V2, V8, V9} | select(.V9 ==3) | select(.V2 =="Male")';
```

This is what the script shows

```
Women
--------------
{"V1":38,"V2":"Female","V8":5.6,"V9":3}
{"V1":38,"V2":"Female","V8":5.6,"V9":3}
{"V1":32,"V2":"Female","V8":6,"V9":3}
{"V1":31,"V2":"Female","V8":6,"V9":3}
{"V1":19,"V2":"Female","V8":5.5,"V9":3}
{"V1":38,"V2":"Female","V8":7,"V9":3}
{"V1":20,"V2":"Female","V8":6.1,"V9":3}
{"V1":32,"V2":"Female","V8":7,"V9":3}
{"V1":42,"V2":"Female","V8":6.7,"V9":3}
 
Men
-------------
{"V1":72,"V2":"Male","V8":7.4,"V9":3}
{"V1":60,"V2":"Male","V8":6.3,"V9":3}
{"V1":33,"V2":"Male","V8":5.4,"V9":3}
{"V1":60,"V2":"Male","V8":6.8,"V9":3}
{"V1":60,"V2":"Male","V8":7.4,"V9":3}
{"V1":60,"V2":"Male","V8":7,"V9":3}
{"V1":72,"V2":"Male","V8":6.2,"V9":3}
```

And this is what I want to show

```
Women
--------------
38,Female,3, 5.6
38,Female,3, 5.6
32,Female,3, 6
31,Female,3, 6
19,Female,3, 5.5
38,Female,3, 7
20,Female,3, 6.1
32,Female,3, 7
42,Female,3, 6.7

Men
--------------
72,Male,3, 7.4
60,Male,3, 6.3
33,Male,3, 5.4
60,Male,3, 6.8
60,Male,3, 7.4
60,Male,3, 7
72,Male,3, 6.2
```

So, how can I hide the key values and only show the content of the JSON after doing the filters I did?

Comment: @Cyrus `csvjson.json`is the name of the json file and it works properly. I don't think this is the problem, sorry. I just show how it looks like  but just a part of it as I mentioned. Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Do you want to print **all** lines or just those that match `.V9 == 3`?

Comment: @pmf all lines that meet the conditions: .V9 == 3, .V2 ="Female" and show .V1, .V2, .V3 ,.V9 as it is shown in 'my scripts shows...'

Comment: Just asking, because all your example data has `3.3` in the `.V9` fields (not `3`), so none would be shown, right? Or do you want to print `3` instead of the actual `.V9` value?

Comment: @pmf I don't think so. All ```.V9``` values equal 3. --> ```{"V1":38,"V2":"Female","V8":5.6,"V9":3}
{"V1":38,"V2":"Female","V8":5.6,"V9":3}
{"V1":32,"V2":"Female","V8":6,"V9":3}
{"V1":31,"V2":"Female","V8":6,"V9":3}```

Comment: In your example data above (under "This is how the json looks like") there is no record with `.v9` being equal to `3`.

Comment: @Cyrus, I redo the initial file to end in ```]``` as is expected from your side. However, my intention was just to show that the json didn't consist only in those values.

Comment: @pmf, this is correct. That's why I'm trying to select only those cases in which .V9 equals 3. Apart of that, I want to select by gender and once these 2 conditions are met (gender + value =3) I want to get the 4 values shown (V1, V2, V8 and V9).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accomplished entirely within `jq` (although some constraints are not all clear, so please comment and I will update the code):

```
jq --raw-output '

  group_by(.V2)[]
  | if first.V2 == "Male" then "Men" else "Women" end,
    "--------------",
    (
      .[]
      | select(.V9 == 3.3)    # this filters to matching records
      | [.V1, .V2, .V9, .V8]
      | join(",")
    )

' csvjson.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Dupidz6DRK)

Comment: unfortunately this gives the following: ```{
  "V1": 38,
  "V2": "Female",
  "V8": 5.6,
  "V9": 3
}
{
  "V1": 38,
  "V2": "Female",
  "V8": 5.6,
  "V9": 3
}``` but differs from the expected result as you can see

Comment: You are working on other data than you provided in your question. Your example data from above (under "This is how the json looks like") does not contain any record with `.v9` being equal to `3`. Also, my code eventually produces strings (due to the `--raw-output` option), not objects with fields. Try the demo I provided, modify it, and post your link as response.

Comment: sorry, but in the code you are showing, I can't see where is the value 3 selected. As far as I can see, your are grouping by V2 selecting the values V1,V2,V8 and V9. Did I unterstand well?

Comment: Updated the code to filter for matching records.

Comment: Did you know you can make a stand-alone jq script with a shebang of `#!/usr/bin/env -S jq --raw-output --from-file` and even have your code block here have syntax highlight if you specify `jq` as the code block language?

Comment: No, I didn't. Regarding this and similar answers, however, it strongly depends on the context how you intend to apply the snippets from SO. If one, potentially large jq script is all you are going to execute, that's fine. But if you have many smaller snippets interwoven with, for instance, handling files, querying a database etc, you'd be better off just calling jq from within a main bash script or whatever rather than having them scattered across several files. But again, it all depends on the use case context, so thank you for pointing out this feature, it could definitely be useful at times

Comment: (And afaik SO's markdown has no jq support.)

Comment: Unfortunately, someone can still submit one though

Comment: `join(",")` should be `csv`

Answer (score 0):

Demo stand-alone `jq` script and code bloc language highlight for use here in stack sites using [pmf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69694963/7939871)'s answer.

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S jq --raw-output --from-file

group_by(.V2)[]
| if first.V2 == "Male" then "Men" else "Women" end,
  "--------------",
  (
    .[]
    | select(.V9 == 3.3)    # this filters to matching records
    | [.V1, .V2, .V9, .V8]
    | join(",")
  )
```